# How to define specific substitution rules for each captured group?

Tags: c++, regex, substitution, capture-group

Say I would like to substitute any chain of non-digit characters with CHARS and any chain of digit characters with DIGITS. How can I substitute $1 with CHARS and $2 with DIGITS only? There does not seem to be a way to do this easily with a regular substitute method?

For instance
Original:

```
abcdef-012-abde
```

Substituted:

```
CHARS-DIGITS-CHARS
```

I have implemented a corresponding regex on regex101 https://regex101.com/r/Qpad2O/2

Comment: Which langage ?

Comment: c++ preferably.

Comment: I mean of course one could apply two regex-substitution transformations in a row.

Comment: And what's the problem with doing so? As that seems like the most obvious and fastest way to do it. I'm no c++ expert but that what I would do in like JS or PHP

Comment: Not that I don't like regex in general but wouldn't it be easier to write in C++ without? [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a68c4b8e7387dc9d) (...not to mention that it's probably faster.)

Comment: Well there is no problem per se I guess. I was just wondering if there would be a way of doing it all at once, theoretically.

Comment: @Scheff kind of off-topic. The given regex is just an example to illustrate the double-substitution problem.